# No Wi-Fi Adapter found, iwlwifi problem?

Tags: drivers, wireless, iwlwifi, dmesg

I am working on a HP ProBook and Ubuntu 22.04 and have the problem, that when trying to connect via WiFi that no WiFi adapter is found.

As I am not really practiced with Ubuntu, I tried my best to follow forum recommendations I found but soon came to my limits:

I tried the following steps:

1. Reset BIOS to default setting, but turn off Fast Boot in BIOS.
2. Check if the right drivers are installed.
3. Check if iwlwifi is working (came to an error message I wasn't able to resolve).

```
*-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 20
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:600324c000-600324ffff

00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at 600324c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [164] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0010 Rev=0 Len=014 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

`rfkill all list` returns:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi` returns

```
[10432.181410] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[10432.181431] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[10432.181454] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80290033 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[10432.181477] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00090006 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[10432.181482] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A482 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[10432.181503] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[10432.181509] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[10432.181529] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[10432.181534] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[10432.181556] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[10432.181563] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[10432.181587] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[10432.181611] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[10432.181631] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00090006 | FSEQ_PREV_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[10432.181636] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00290033 | FSEQ_WIFI_FSEQ_VERSION
[10432.181658] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00290033 | FSEQ_BT_FSEQ_VERSION
[10432.181663] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000001AE | FSEQ_CLASS_TP_VERSION
[10432.181691] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC CURRENT PC: 0x80472b34
[10432.181712] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC1 CURRENT PC: 0xd0
[10432.181717] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[10432.181721] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[10433.104433] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[10433.116894] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 2
```

Comment: Is it a dual boot?

Comment: @Pilot6 No it’s not dual boot